# Python Turtle Issue

Tags: python

I am tryig to create a turtle game where two players can chase around a "goal" shape. I am struggling to get the program to recognize that two shapes are close to each other and therefore that one player should receive a point and then the goal should move. I have pasted my code below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import turtle as trtl
import random as rand

#initialization / game setup
wn = trtl.Screen()


player1 = trtl.Turtle()
player1.shape('turtle')
player1.fillcolor('red')
player1.penup()
player1.goto(rand.randint(-100,100),rand.randint(-100,100))

player2 = trtl.Turtle()
player2.shape('triangle')
player2.fillcolor('blue')
player2.penup()
player2.goto(rand.randint(-100,100),rand.randint(-100,100))

goal = trtl.Turtle()
goal.shape('circle')
goal.fillcolor('yellow')
goal.penup()
goal.goto(rand.randint(-200,200),rand.randint(-150,-150))



player1_score = 0
player2_score = 0

def player1_up():
    player1.setheading(90)
    player1.forward(10)

def player2_up():
    player2.setheading(90)
    player2.forward(10)

def player1_down():
    player1.setheading(270)
    player1.forward(10)

def player2_down():
    player2.setheading(270)
    player2.forward(10)

def player1_right():
    player1.setheading(0)
    player1.forward(10)

def player2_right():
    player2.setheading(0)
    player2.forward(10)

def player1_left():
    player1.setheading(180)
    player1.forward(10)

def player2_left():
    player2.setheading(180)
    player2.forward(10)

if (abs(player1.xcor() - goal.xcor())<5):
  if (abs(player1.ycor() - goal.ycor())<5):
    player1_score+=1
    goal.goto(rand.randint(-200,200),rand.randint(-150,150))
    print(player1_score)


#events
wn.onkeypress(player1_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(player2_up, "i")

wn.onkeypress(player1_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(player2_down, "k")

wn.onkeypress(player1_right, "d")
wn.onkeypress(player2_right, "l")

wn.onkeypress(player1_left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(player2_left, "j")


wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

I tried to simplify the code and I have seen this work in other programs. However, I cannot get it to work here!

Comment: Two basic problems here: 1) you're checking the player's X coordinate twice, and the Y coordinate not at all; 2) you're performing this check *once*, as your program starts up.  You need to perform the check *after each movement*, so put it in a function and call that function from all of the player's movement functions. (Note that turtles have a `.distance(otherTurtle)` method that would make the check a lot simpler than you're currently writing it.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually mistyped me own code in here and then had to edit the post to correct the x.cor() occuring twice. But I did create a function to check under each movement and it worked. I also implemented .distance and greatly simplified the code. Thank you!